# Linux Mint/Ubuntu refuses to suspend laptop

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, linux-mint, thinkpad

I have a laptop running a Ubuntu distro that refuses not suspend. This happens about 3 times a week. The experience is you either close the lid, or send the system into suspend from the shut down dialogue. The laptop starts to suspend, display goes off, half-moon led flicks and then 2 seconds later it flicks again and wakes up!

The pause is long enough to not noticed and you already have the laptop in the bag, only to pick it out later still on and very hot! (if it has full battery)

btw.. Hibernate / Suspend to Disk doesn't work either, it also wakes up again.

- Lenovo T430s 2356GDG
- OS Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon X86_64 3.13.0-27-generic
- CPU: Intel i5-3320M 2x 2.6Ghz
- RAM: 2x 8GB DDR3
- SSHSamsung 840 256GB

BIOS Information
    Vendor: LENOVO
    Version: G7ET99WW (2.59 )
    Release Date: 03/18/2014

**Output of Dmesg**
In a few places you can see some CPU issues and some devices become not hot-pluggable. But in other cases it works

```
[151941.226633] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[151941.245684] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[151941.245916] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.122 seconds) done.
[151941.368492] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[151941.370005] PM: Entering mem sleep
[151941.370054] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[151941.497802] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[151941.499748] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[151942.449032] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Hardware Error
[151943.175599] pci_pm_suspend(): e1000_suspend+0x0/0x20 [e1000e] returns -2
[151943.175602] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -2
[151943.175605] PM: Device 0000:00:19.0 failed to suspend async: error -2
[151943.175656] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[151943.175755] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[151943.190689] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[151943.510564] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[151943.513599] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[151943.513603] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[151943.513794] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[151943.513877] ata1.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[151943.515199] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[151943.515203] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[151943.515368] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[151943.515425] ata1.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[151943.515427] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[151943.518571] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[151943.521998] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[151943.522671] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:03:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[151943.526746] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[151943.527388] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:03:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[151943.528916] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[151943.530652] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[151943.695862] PM: resume of devices complete after 519.861 msecs
[151943.696040] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[151943.696040] Restarting tasks ... done.
[151943.698953] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[151943.824774] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_request_row: arg0 rejected: (0x01:0x00)->0x00
[151943.824778] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_read_row: failed requesting row: (0x01:0x00)->0xfffffffb
[151943.824780] thinkpad_ec: initial ec test failed
[151944.375130] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p on, RC6pp off
[151957.808283] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 28
[151957.810498] rndis_host 1-1.2:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2, RNDIS device
[151957.812847] bridge-usb0: detached
[151958.024924] userif-2: sent link down event.
[151958.024931] userif-2: sent link up event.
[152717.966226] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xd9 on isa0060/serio0).
[152717.966234] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e059 <keycode>' to make it known.
[152717.966666] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xd9 on isa0060/serio0).
[152717.966673] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e059 <keycode>' to make it known.
[152717.968640] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[152717.968668] pci 0000:00:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968673] pci 0000:00:00.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968686] i915 0000:00:02.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968690] i915 0000:00:02.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968703] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968708] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968729] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968734] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968756] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968761] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968782] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968786] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968806] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968815] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968823] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968871] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968879] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968931] sdhci-pci 0000:04:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968940] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968944] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968968] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968972] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: using default PCI settings
[152717.968994] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.968998] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: using default PCI settings
[152717.969018] pci 0000:00:1f.3: no hotplug settings from platform
[152717.969021] pci 0000:00:1f.3: using default PCI settings
[153118.850511] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xd8 on isa0060/serio0).
[153118.850519] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e058 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153118.851057] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xd8 on isa0060/serio0).
[153118.851063] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e058 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153120.567253] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_request_row: arg0 rejected: (0x01:0x00)->0x00
[153120.567262] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_read_row: failed requesting row: (0x01:0x00)->0xfffffffb
[153120.567266] thinkpad_ec: initial ec test failed
[153120.693498] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[153120.711539] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[153120.711818] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[153120.714127] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[153120.715641] PM: Entering mem sleep
[153120.715692] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[153120.837741] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[153120.837981] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[153121.772217] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Hardware Error
[153122.083338] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[153122.083342] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 2882 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/kernel/irq/manage.c:1255 __free_irq+0xa3/0x1e0()
[153122.083342] Trying to free already-free IRQ 20
[153122.083366] Modules linked in: ftdi_sio usbserial snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet mii hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid xt_addrtype xt_conntrack ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack bridge stp llc aufs iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables acpi_call(OF) vmnet(OF) parport_pc vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci vmmon(OF) pci_stub vboxpci(OF) vboxnetadp(OF) vboxnetflt(OF) vboxdrv(OF) cmac rmd160 crypto_null camellia_generic camellia_aesni_avx_x86_64 camellia_x86_64 cast6_avx_x86_64 cast6_generic cast5_avx_x86_64 cast5_generic cast_common deflate cts ctr gcm ccm serpent_avx_x86_64 serpent_sse2_x86_64 serpent_generic blowfish_generic blowfish_x86_64 blowfish_common twofish_generic twofish_avx_x86_64 twofish_x86_64_3way xts twofish_x86_64 twofish_common xcbc sha256_ssse3 sha512_ssse3 des_generic xfrm_user ah6 ah4 esp6 esp4 xfrm4_mode_beet xfrm4_tunnel tunnel4 xfrm4_mode_tunnel xfrm4_mode_transport xfrm6_mode_transport xfrm6_mode_ro xfrm6_mode_beet uvcvideo xfrm6_mode_tunnel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops ipcomp videobuf2_core ipcomp6 videodev xfrm6_tunnel tunnel6 xfrm_ipcomp btusb af_key xfrm_algo snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp arc4 coretemp snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec iwldvm snd_hwdep mac80211 kvm_intel snd_pcm dm_multipath scsi_dh bnep kvm rfcomm thinkpad_acpi bluetooth nvram snd_seq_midi iwlwifi snd_page_alloc crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw cfg80211 gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd joydev serio_raw snd_rawmidi snd_seq lpc_ich snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore mei_me mei mac_hid binfmt_misc ppdev lp parport nls_iso8859_1 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log i915 psmouse ahci libahci e1000e sdhci_pci i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper sdhci ptp drm pps_core wmi video [last unloaded: vmnet]
[153122.083404] CPU: 2 PID: 2882 Comm: kworker/u16:9 Tainted: GF       W  O 3.13.0-27-generic #50-Ubuntu
[153122.083405] Hardware name: LENOVO 2356GDG/2356GDG, BIOS G7ET99WW (2.59 ) 03/18/2014
[153122.083407] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[153122.083409]  0000000000000009 ffff88000ed0dba8 ffffffff817199c4 ffff88000ed0dbf0
[153122.083410]  ffff88000ed0dbe0 ffffffff810676bd ffff880401c18800 ffff880401ef8000
[153122.083411]  0000000000000014 ffff880401c1889c ffff880401c18800 ffff88000ed0dc40
[153122.083411] Call Trace:
[153122.083415]  [<ffffffff817199c4>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[153122.083417]  [<ffffffff810676bd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[153122.083418]  [<ffffffff8106772c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[153122.083419]  [<ffffffff810bfc53>] __free_irq+0xa3/0x1e0
[153122.083420]  [<ffffffff810bfe29>] free_irq+0x49/0xb0
[153122.083429]  [<ffffffffa00b06ad>] e1000_free_irq+0x6d/0x80 [e1000e]
[153122.083435]  [<ffffffffa00bb9c7>] __e1000_shutdown+0x97/0x8a0 [e1000e]
[153122.083443]  [<ffffffffa00bc227>] e1000_suspend+0x17/0x20 [e1000e]
[153122.083445]  [<ffffffff813a62bc>] pci_pm_suspend+0x6c/0x150
[153122.083447]  [<ffffffff813a6250>] ? pci_pm_freeze+0xe0/0xe0
[153122.083448]  [<ffffffff8149a049>] dpm_run_callback+0x49/0xa0
[153122.083449]  [<ffffffff8149a44b>] __device_suspend+0xdb/0x280
[153122.083452]  [<ffffffff8109a66a>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x1fa/0x2c0
[153122.083453]  [<ffffffff8149a60f>] async_suspend+0x1f/0xa0
[153122.083454]  [<ffffffff81091517>] async_run_entry_fn+0x37/0x130
[153122.083456]  [<ffffffff810838a2>] process_one_work+0x182/0x450
[153122.083458]  [<ffffffff81084641>] worker_thread+0x121/0x410
[153122.083459]  [<ffffffff81084520>] ? rescuer_thread+0x3e0/0x3e0
[153122.083461]  [<ffffffff8108b312>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
[153122.083462]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
[153122.083464]  [<ffffffff8172a2fc>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[153122.083465]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
[153122.083466] ---[ end trace c78529d32ee1ccce ]---
[153122.499119] pci_pm_suspend(): e1000_suspend+0x0/0x20 [e1000e] returns -2
[153122.499120] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -2
[153122.499122] PM: Device 0000:00:19.0 failed to suspend async: error -2
[153122.499148] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[153122.499204] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[153122.513763] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[153122.841585] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[153122.841613] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[153122.842915] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[153122.842919] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[153122.843119] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[153122.843207] ata1.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[153122.844527] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[153122.844531] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[153122.844671] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[153122.844735] ata1.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[153122.844737] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[153122.845061] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153122.845743] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:03:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153122.849859] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153122.850503] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:03:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153122.852026] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[153122.865672] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[153123.018832] PM: resume of devices complete after 519.340 msecs
[153123.019009] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[153123.019010] Restarting tasks ... done.
[153123.026726] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[153123.149979] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_request_row: arg0 rejected: (0x01:0x00)->0x00
[153123.149983] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_read_row: failed requesting row: (0x01:0x00)->0xfffffffb
[153123.149985] thinkpad_ec: initial ec test failed
[153124.174467] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p on, RC6pp off
[153125.268967] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[153127.299892] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xd9 on isa0060/serio0).
[153127.299900] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e059 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153127.300330] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xd9 on isa0060/serio0).
[153127.300334] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e059 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153127.301877] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[153127.301902] pci 0000:00:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.301907] pci 0000:00:00.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.301922] i915 0000:00:02.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.301927] i915 0000:00:02.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.301939] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.301943] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.301964] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.301969] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.301990] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.301995] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.302015] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302020] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.302040] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302047] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302054] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302100] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302109] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302311] sdhci-pci 0000:04:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302319] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302323] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.302345] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302349] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: using default PCI settings
[153127.302369] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302374] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: using default PCI settings
[153127.302390] pci 0000:00:1f.3: no hotplug settings from platform
[153127.302393] pci 0000:00:1f.3: using default PCI settings
[153129.668681] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xd8 on isa0060/serio0).
[153129.668688] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e058 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153129.669264] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xd8 on isa0060/serio0).
[153129.669270] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e058 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153131.307774] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_request_row: arg0 rejected: (0x01:0x00)->0x00
[153131.307781] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_read_row: failed requesting row: (0x01:0x00)->0xfffffffb
[153131.307784] thinkpad_ec: initial ec test failed
[153131.447794] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[153131.466844] PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
[153131.466968] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
[153131.469340] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[153131.470914] PM: Entering mem sleep
[153131.470964] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[153131.593456] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[153131.593705] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[153132.543725] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Hardware Error
[153132.855282] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[153132.855286] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 2950 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/kernel/irq/manage.c:1255 __free_irq+0xa3/0x1e0()
[153132.855287] Trying to free already-free IRQ 20
[153132.855311] Modules linked in: 
[153132.855355] Call Trace:
[153132.855359]  [<ffffffff817199c4>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[153132.855361]  [<ffffffff810676bd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[153132.855362]  [<ffffffff8106772c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
[153132.855363]  [<ffffffff810bfc53>] __free_irq+0xa3/0x1e0
[153132.855364]  [<ffffffff810bfe29>] free_irq+0x49/0xb0
[153132.855373]  [<ffffffffa00b06ad>] e1000_free_irq+0x6d/0x80 [e1000e]
[153132.855380]  [<ffffffffa00bb9c7>] __e1000_shutdown+0x97/0x8a0 [e1000e]
[153132.855382]  [<ffffffff813a3978>] ? pci_disable_device+0x48/0xb0
[153132.855390]  [<ffffffffa00bc227>] e1000_suspend+0x17/0x20 [e1000e]
[153132.855392]  [<ffffffff813a62bc>] pci_pm_suspend+0x6c/0x150
[153132.855394]  [<ffffffff813a6250>] ? pci_pm_freeze+0xe0/0xe0
[153132.855396]  [<ffffffff8149a049>] dpm_run_callback+0x49/0xa0
[153132.855397]  [<ffffffff8149a44b>] __device_suspend+0xdb/0x280
[153132.855399]  [<ffffffff8109a66a>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x1fa/0x2c0
[153132.855400]  [<ffffffff8149a60f>] async_suspend+0x1f/0xa0
[153132.855401]  [<ffffffff81091517>] async_run_entry_fn+0x37/0x130
[153132.855403]  [<ffffffff810838a2>] process_one_work+0x182/0x450
[153132.855405]  [<ffffffff81084641>] worker_thread+0x121/0x410
[153132.855406]  [<ffffffff81084520>] ? rescuer_thread+0x3e0/0x3e0
[153132.855408]  [<ffffffff8108b312>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
[153132.855409]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
[153132.855411]  [<ffffffff8172a2fc>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[153132.855412]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
[153132.855413] ---[ end trace c78529d32ee1cccf ]---
[153133.271069] pci_pm_suspend(): e1000_suspend+0x0/0x20 [e1000e] returns -2
[153133.271071] dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -2
[153133.271073] PM: Device 0000:00:19.0 failed to suspend async: error -2
[153133.271111] PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[153133.271167] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[153133.284881] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[153133.608666] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[153133.611704] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[153133.611708] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[153133.611913] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[153133.611972] ata1.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[153133.613299] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[153133.613303] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[153133.613462] ata1.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
[153133.613526] ata1.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
[153133.613528] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[153133.636748] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[153133.668702] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[153133.671679] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153133.672325] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:03:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153133.677119] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:10:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153133.677769] ata2.00: ACPI cmd e3/00:03:00:00:00:a0 (IDLE) succeeded
[153133.679371] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[153133.789827] PM: resume of devices complete after 518.373 msecs
[153133.789981] PM: Finishing wakeup.
[153133.789982] Restarting tasks ... done.
[153133.796796] video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
[153133.895333] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_request_row: arg0 rejected: (0x01:0x00)->0x00
[153133.895337] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec_read_row: failed requesting row: (0x01:0x00)->0xfffffffb
[153133.895339] thinkpad_ec: initial ec test failed
[153135.169702] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p on, RC6pp off
[153785.777976] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xd9 on isa0060/serio0).
[153785.777983] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e059 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153785.778427] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xd9 on isa0060/serio0).
[153785.778431] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e059 <keycode>' to make it known.
[153785.780083] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[153785.780109] pci 0000:00:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780114] pci 0000:00:00.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780128] i915 0000:00:02.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780133] i915 0000:00:02.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780145] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780150] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780171] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780176] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780195] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780198] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780214] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780217] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780230] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780236] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780241] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780283] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780288] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780414] sdhci-pci 0000:04:00.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780422] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780426] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780445] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780449] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: using default PCI settings
[153785.780469] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780474] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: using default PCI settings
[153785.780492] pci 0000:00:1f.3: no hotplug settings from platform
[153785.780497] pci 0000:00:1f.3: using default PCI settings
[153834.904437] ata2.00: disabled
[153834.909566] ata2.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
[153834.909694] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.SAT1.PRT1: undocking
```

As this could be many different things, My plan is to have a suspend script that detects if the computer has resumed, and start to kill/shutdown process that are blocking the system from suspending. It would iterate continuously until eventually it can suspend. Or it just shuts the HW down. Regardless of what applications are going to lose data doesn't matter as if it doesn't suspend i just manually do `"sudo shutdown -h now"`

Answer (score 1):

Can you add some information about the devices connected to your laptop?
The log shows an error `e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Hardware Error` [Here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7289060.html) you can find a possible solution (it is Gentoo forum).
Try to suspend your laptop without the network cable.